# HTML slider doubles pendulum speed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a pendulum in HTML/JS and have its angular velocity and angle controlled by ranges. both of the ranges work changing what they're intend to, but each time the value of the ranges is changed it seems to heavily increase the speed of the pendulum if the speed or angle is increased 
or decreased the speed.

Here's the HTML/JavaScript Snippet

```js
    var canvas = ctx = false;
    var frameRate = 1/40;
    var frameDelay = frameRate * 1000;

    /*used to change the angle and the velocity of the pendulum*/
    var arcSlider = document.getElementById("arc");
    var velocitySlider = document.getElementById('velocity');
    var arcNumber = document.getElementById("arcNum");
    var velocityNumber = document.getElementById("velocityNum");
    var arc = (arcSlider.value / 100);
    var velocity = velocitySlider.value;

    /*sets the values for the pendulum*/
    var pendulum = {mass: 100, length:300, theta: (Math.PI/2) - arc , omega: 0, alpha:0, J:0};

    /*listener for angl slider*/
    arcSlider.addEventListener("change", function(){
        arcNumber.innerHTML = "arc: " + (arcSlider.value / 100);
        arc = arcSlider.value / 100;
        init();
    });

    /*listener for velocity slider*/
    velocitySlider.addEventListener("change", function(){
        velocityNumber.innerHTML = "velocity: " + velocitySlider.value;
        velocity = velocitySlider.value;
        init();
    });

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame   || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
            function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
    })();

    function init() {
        pendulum.J = pendulum.mass * pendulum.length * pendulum.length / velocity;
        lastTime = new Date();
        requestAnimFrame(draw);  
    }

    /*loop for pendulum*/
 function draw(){  
        var width = 1000, height = 600;
     var len = 150;
        var timeMs = (new Date()).getTime();
        var deltaT = (timeMs - lastTime.getTime()) / 1000; 
      
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
        if (deltaT > 0.050)
        {
            deltaT = 0.050;
        }
    
        deltaT = 0.01;
      
        /* Calculate current position*/
        pendulum.theta += pendulum.omega * deltaT + (.5 * pendulum.alpha * deltaT * deltaT );  
      
        /* calculates force */
        var T = pendulum.mass * 9.81 * Math.cos(pendulum.theta) * pendulum.length;  
      
        /* Current acceleration */
        var alpha = T / pendulum.J;   
      
        /*Calculate current velocity*/
        pendulum.omega += .5 * (alpha + pendulum.alpha) * deltaT;   
      
        /* Update acceleration */
        pendulum.alpha = alpha;    
      
        /*sets the current x and y for the pendulum*/
        var bobX = width/2 + pendulum.length * Math.cos(pendulum.theta);
        var bobY = pendulum.length * Math.sin(pendulum.theta);
    
        /*clears the canvas*/
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height)
    
        /*canvas line*/
        ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(width/2,0);
     ctx.lineTo(bobX,bobY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    
        /*canvas pendulum*/
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(bobX,bobY,16,0 ,Math.PI * 2 , false);
     ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    
     requestAnimationFrame(draw);  
    }
    init();
```

```html
        <div href="#0" class="button"> 
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="400">
            </canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderOutline">
            <div class="sliderContainer">
                <p>Change the arc of the pendulum:</p>
                <input type="range" name="arcRange"min="5" max="80" value="40"   class="slider" id="arc">
                <p>Change the velocity:</p>
                <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="500" class="slider" id="velocity" >
                <div>
                    <p id="arcNum">arc: 0.4 </p>
                </div>
              <div>
                    <p id="velocityNum">velocity: 500</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code for `init()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `init()`, `init()` calls `requestAnimationFrame(draw)` and of course `draw` calls `requestAnimationFrame(draw)` as is a common pattern.

However when you call `init()` a second time (e.g. when the user modifies a slider) then you call `requestAnimationFrame(draw)` again. When the browser determines it's time for an animation frame, `draw` will get called twice.

There's a stack of functions that will get called every time an animation frame is ready to be requested. If you call `requestAnimationFrame` once, then the stack get's one entry of `draw` pushed on to it. When the animation frame is ready that stack is popped until it's empty, and the functions get called one at a time. It's common practice to push on one function that will push itself back onto that stack with another call to `requestAnimationFrame` right at the end.

When you call `requestAnimationFrame` multiple times from outside this normal loop, you end up with multiple functions in that stack that all get called each animation frame. Because your `draw` function modifies the state of your pendulum each time it's called, calling it twice as often will make the pendulum move twice as fast. Click around on your slider 5 or 6 times and it'll rock back and forth like crazy.

As a quick fix, you can modify init like so:

```
function init(begin) {
  pendulum.mass = 100;
  pendulum.theta = (Math.PI/2) - arc;
  pendulum.omega = 0;
  pendulum.alpha = 0;
  pendulum.J = pendulum.mass * pendulum.length * pendulum.length / velocity;

  lastTime = new Date();
  if (begin) requestAnimFrame(draw);  
}
```

And at the very bottom of your javascript you'd call:

```
init(true);
```

As shown with [an updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KooKbv). It's not the best solution, just a minimal solution to show that not calling `requestAnimationFrame` multiple times should provide the results you're looking for.

Comment: I knew i was overlooking a simple logic problem. Thanks for the great response.